# How to ensure only one record is active

Tags: cakephp

I want that when a record is saved and marked as active, all other records are marked INactive.

I've tried the following code in my model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data['Ticket']['is_active'])) {
        $this->data['Ticket']['is_active'] = 0;     
    }
    return true;
}
```

However this code is error

Comment: please any idea for my problem !!

Comment: "This code is error" <-- please clarify

Comment: I have a table tickets have field statut  (0 or 1). i want if create a ticket with satut equal 1 so  will be others ticket update statut at 0. 
So there is only one ticket with the statut 1

Comment: I hope that you have understood because I'm not good in English

Comment: To clarify - If a ticket (a single row/ record in the tickets table) has its status column equal to 1, you want all other rows (records) in the ticket table to have their status column assigned 0. Is that true?

Comment: I understood what you want - but you said it has an error.  Please clarify what error, what's not working...etc

Comment: yes it's true. @AgRizzo

Answer (score 2):

### Use afterSave

Instead of using beforeSave, it's more appropriate to use [afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave), and [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) like so:

```
public function afterSave($created) {
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['is_active'])) {
        $this->updateAll(
            array('is_active' => 0),
            array(
                'id !=' => $this->id,
                'is_active' => 1
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I.e. *after* successfully saving *a* record, if it is active disable all the others.

*Note: be sure to use the same method signature as the parent class. It varies depending on which version of CakePHP you are using*.

Comment: this error display **Strict (2048): Declaration of Ticket::afterSave() should be compatible with Model::afterSave($created) [APP\Model\Ticket.php, line 30]**

Comment: **Strict (2048): Declaration of Ticket::afterSave() should be compatible with Model::afterSave($created) [APP\Model\Ticket.php, line 22]**

Comment: I've read the error message for you and edited the answer to suit. If you don't understand the message - _ask what it means_, though it should be rather obvious.

Comment: +1 for figuring out what the heck the OP was asking. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write before save method like

```
public function beforeSave($options=array()){

 if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['is_active'])) {

                $this->data[$this->alias]['is_active'] = 0;

        }
        return true;

}
```

Comment: `public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data['Modelticket']['is_active']) ) {
           $this->updateAll(
            array('is_active' => 0),
            array(
                'id !=' => $this->id,
                'is_active' => 1
            )
        );
    }
    return true;
}`

Comment: ça fonctionne trés bien